# I want to use index about randomly index in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I use Java. when I use ArrayList in Java. if I access index number randomly.

Is this posible?

If this is not posible. How should I do?

For example

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add(100,"stackoverflow");
```

Is this posible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to access a random item in the `ArrayList` based on its index?

Comment: So do you have an ArrayList containing some objects and want to choose one of the objects randomly?

Comment: @pamiers See the edited part of my answer

Comment: To those wondering : I think that by Random, OP meant arbitrary, like in Random Access File.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you seem to need isn't an arrayList but a map between integers and strings :

```
HashMap<Integer,String> mymap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

So you can write

```
mymap.put(100,"stackoverflow");
```

And

```
String myString = mymap.get(100);
```

Adding onto why you cannot use an arraylist:

When you first initialize an ArrayList, the size is zero. Attempting to add at an index that is larger than the size will still throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception just like an array would. The benefit of the ArrayList is that it will dynamically allocate more memory should the size fill up.

Besides, arrays aren't efficient for "sparse arrays" even if you make the effort to manage the size to avoid errors.

Comment: Oh, I see.. ArrayList is not? Anyway, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = (int)(Math.random() * myArray.size());
Object o = myArray.get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ya... you can..** ArrayList gives lots of flexibility, like remove, add, indexOf..etc..

**Eg:**

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

arr.add("vivek");
arr.add("vicky");

arr.get(1);
```

**Edited part:**

If directly you try to add the element on the 100th when the size is less than that, you will get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

Answer (score 0):

`Is this posible?`

Yes you can.Like below

```
   List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i <10;i++)
    {
        list.add(i,new Integer(i).toString());
    }

    System.out.println(list.get(5));
```

If you want to use Random Number then you should generate number and you can add to that index.