# Getting values in Multimaps - Guava

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I use Guava library.

Is there any way to get in Multimap in each value?

For example, The value is 1=[stack], 2=[over, flow], 3=[com] in Multimap. If Multimap name is map and key is 2, `map.get("2")` will appear [over, flow].

I want to get only "flow". Is it posible?

Comment: You can try `.get(1)` I'm not at all sure about the return type of `map.get("2")`, though.

Comment: Oh my god! I guess stupid thing.

Comment: Based on your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427031/i-want-to-use-index-about-randomly-index-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444628/if-i-use-hashmapstring-arrayliststring-in-java I would suggest that you what you are trying to achieve needs a bit more thought. Think about your higher level concept once more and ask a question about that if necessary (e.g. *I want to cache entries where the key is an arbitrary integer; the cache should return one of the elements if queried*)

Answer (score 5):

A Multimap returns a `Collection<X>`, it sounds like you need the last item in that list, in that case you just need to get the list by calling `map.get("2")` and retrieve the last/n-th item in the list.

Guava has a class named `Iterables` which could prove useful to you. for example

```
String lastValue = Iterables.getLast(your_list);
```